# Plotting with four colors for only two legend elements?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table with the rows g and gt^y, both simulated for two different economies. Now I want to plot all of them in the same plot. Each line of points should have a different color and the legend should show  the two colors per economy. Is there any way to do this?

```
ggplot(title = "Evolution of gt^y and gt in the first 100 periods")+
  geom_point(data = result[c(1:101,1002:1102),], mapping = aes(x = period, y = g, color = economy))+
  geom_point(data = result[c(1:101,1002:1102),], mapping = aes(x = period, y = `gt^y`, color = economy))+
  ylab("g / gt^y")
```

Comment: hello :) my guess is that you should put `aes(..., color = economy)` inside `ggplot(...)` but I can't test it out unless you provide some data example to work with. If this does not work, you can do anything you wan using `sclales_*_*()` functions.

Comment: I don't think I can put the aes in economy since one mapping is x=period, y=g while the other has to be x=period, y=gt^y

Comment: you can define aes within `ggplot()` AND `geom_*()`. I am more concerned by the fact you want 2 different y axis on your plot. Again, without any data to work with it will be very difficult to go further. Could you please add? You can use `head(yourdata)`, `dput(yourdata)`, use a  base R dataset (such as `mtcars` or `iris`) or even use your own build example for us to recreate your problem.